# Windows 7 Touch Screen "Shrug"

Tags: wpf, windows, listview, touch

We've got a WPF app that runs on Win 7. With touch gestures on in Win 7, while scrolling a ListView, the application "shrugs" on the screen when the end of the list is reached.

This can be reproduced in Internet Explorer as well. If you load a web page that is long enough to produce a scroll bar, Windows "shrugs" IE when the bottom of the page is reached while scrolling with touch gestures.

Is there a way to turn off the shrug in Windows or disable it in some way with code in my WPF app? I need to keep touch on, just turn off the shrug.

Comment: Also I should add, I think it only does this when the app is full screen.

Comment: This is called ["boundary feedback"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371416.aspx), and you should be able to turn it off for your own window(s).  Not sure about system-wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the `ManipulationBoundaryFeedback` (i.e. `e.Handled = true`).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable the boundary for all controls in a window, you should put the `ManipulationBoundaryFeedback` handle on the first panel of the window, not on the window itself.

Doesn't work:

```
<Window x:Class="TestControls.BoundaryFeedback"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="Control_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback"
        >
</Window>
```

Works:

```
<Window x:Class="TestControls.BoundaryFeedback"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        >
    <Grid ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="Control_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In code behind:

```
private void Control_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Great! I struggled with this problem for a long time. It is really not clear that handling this on the Window does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable boundary feedback system-wide.

It's on the Panning tab of the "Pen and Touch" control panel.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OObTOSglE1w