# Touch screen pull down white space above page

Tags: internet-explorer, touch

When a web page loads on a touch screen device it is possible to scroll up (by pulling your finger down) even when the scroll bar is already at the top of the page. When the user removes their finger from the screen the page scrolls back to its default position. This often seems to be used to add a 'refresh' type functionality in iPhone apps for a 'pull down to refresh' feature.

This 'feature' is causing some annoying things to happen in a flex application that I am building and I would like to stop it happening. Does anyone know:

1. The name of this feature;
2. How to turn it off?

Strangely, the boundary effect only occurs once. After it occurs it doesn't happen again and my Flex app is fine.

I am using a Microsoft Surface RT which only comes with Internet Explorer 10 but I assume it is common to all touch screen devices and all browsers.

I tried the following as suggested in a basic HTML page but it didn't have any effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
        }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ManipulationBoundaryFeedback:

[Windows 7 Touch Screen "Shrug"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451873/windows-7-touch-screen-shrug?rq=1)

Windows RT doesn't seem to have that option but that is obviously what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the methods described here: [MSDN: Pointer and Gesture Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You'll need a block of code like this:

```
element.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Here's another example: [PhoneGap: Prevent Scrolling](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Prevent-Scrolling)

Hope that helps!